# I can't use mouse move to select my code in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode9

Developer environment: Xcode 9.0

[image: LookTheImage]

problem:

When I release the left mouse button, the selected state of the code will be canceled.

---

I upgraded my Xcode to version 9.1, not solve.

Comment: Only in XCode? But seems more a question for https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you tried to restart your whole application and system

Comment: Thx for every one. the problem seem the system's bug .I upgrade mac os version is to fix the problem. It seems that a specific version of Appstore's history is not compatible with Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a specific version of Appstore's history is not compatible with Mac OS.
I upgrade macos version ,then everything is ok.